# Publish Karma unit tests in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, karma-runner

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) already builds my Maven Java project. I want the results of [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) unit tests to show up in Jenkins, but unfortunately I cannot introduce any configuration changes in Jenkins. How karma should be configured to acomplish that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- in order for Jenkins to be able to parse karma test results they must be published in the Junit XML format, the plugin that does that is [karma-junit-reporter](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-junit-reporter)
- junit test results (`outputFile` in the karma configuration file) must be stored in `target/surefire-reports/TESTS-TestSuite.xml`

Answer (score 2):

```
    reporters        : ['progress', 'junit', 'coverage'],
    port             : 9876,
    colors           : true,
    logLevel         : config.LOG_INFO,
    // don't watch for file change
    autoWatch        : false,
    // only runs on headless browser
    browsers         : ['PhantomJS'],
    // just run one time
    singleRun        : true,
    // remove `karma-chrome-launcher` because we will be running on PhantomJS
    // browser on Jenkins
    plugins          : [
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-junit-reporter',
        'karma-coverage',
        'karma-jenkins-reporter'
    ],
    // changes type to `cobertura`
    coverageReporter : {
        type : 'cobertura',
        dir  : 'target/coverage-reports/'
    },
    // saves report at `target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml` because Jenkins
    // looks for this location and file prefix by default.
    junitReporter    : {
        outputDir : 'target/surefire-reports/'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but top result in Google.

1. Configure karma.conf.js to use 'karma-junit-reporter' and report to outputDir = 'target/karma-reports/'
2. In your pom.xml, give the test execution step an execution/id like 'karmaTests'
3. In your pom.xml, set a property jenkins.karmaTest.reportsDirectory = target/karma-reports

Full examples are on [this blog post](https://funneltravel.wordpress.com/2017/10/16/running-karma-with-maven-on-jenkins-ci/).