# Jenkins to publish two result reports

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

i have 2 test reports. One for backend i.e. junit and one for front end i.e. karma.

i have to publish test result to jenkins. For junit there is plugin. but for karma there is not.

What can be used.

As of now i tried using junit and xunit to publish the report. But what jenkins is doing here is -- "It is merging both the result reports into a single trend graph."

Comment: I think you can publish Karma test result in Junit XML format wtih `karma-junit-reporter`, and then with Junit Jenkins plugin you can publish both results. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27616658/3473444

Comment: i tried using xunit to publish the karma test result. but jenkins is merging both the reports in same graph.. i want to display it in separate graph.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you can get Karma to publish in JUnit format.
Alternatively, if it can output HTML, you can publish those: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/htmlpublisher/

Comment: I have generated the XML file and tried publishing the result using the xunit plugin. but i found that jenkins is merging both the output and displaying it in single graph.

Answer (score 0):

Karma is a test runner for JavaScript. (for angular that runs jasmine test cases)
For Karma, you can use "karma-junit-reporter" which will generate an XML file of test cases and then use publish JUnit reporter from post-build action  and give path of that XML file

Comment: The issue is jenkins is merging both the reports